# Trouble with updating out-dated WebDriver IO automation repo to latest version

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, webdriver, ui-automation

I would like to update my `synchronous` framework to latest WebDriver IO version.

I'm constantly getting this "unsupported engine" warnings.

Guessing the reason is this part `required: { node: '>=12.0.0 <16' }`

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@wdio/sync@7.27.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=12.0.0 <16' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.18.2', npm: '9.8.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

I'm using this package for `sync` methods`https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wdio/sync`

One more question, should I, at this point, re-write the entire repo to `async` or is there another solution?

E.g. I've ran `npm install webdriverio` command that added some packages but did not update the webdriver version.

Also tried updating packages one-by-one but I'm getting dependencie conflicts that I do not know how to fix, or where as a matter of fact ^^.

EDIT: Tried instaling exact version i.e. `npm install webdriverio@8.20.0` no success.

Here are my `dependencies` & `devDependencies` in `package.json`

```
    "devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^7.7.7",
    "@wdio/cli": "^7.16.14",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^7.7.3",
    "@wdio/dot-reporter": "^7.7.7",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.16.14",
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^7.33.0",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.7.3",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "chai-files": "^1.4.0",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.1.1",
    "wdio-wait-for": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@wdio/sync": "^7.27.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "chromedriver": "^116.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "faker": "^5.5.3",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "mocha": "^9.2.0",
    "mochawesome": "^7.0.1",
    "node-2fa": "^2.0.3",
    "qs": "^6.10.3",
    "wdio-image-comparison-service": "^3.1.0",
    "wdio-rerun-service": "^1.7.3",
    "webdriverio": "^8.20.0"
  }
```

Thanks in advance ^^